# Error: AVD 2.3 is not valid: Unknown target 'android-10' in /home/user/.android/avd/2.3.ini. Try to repair it through AVD manager

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

I get the above error when trying to add the '2.3' named AVD to the Run Configuration. The creation of it worked flawlessly though. Tried on multiple targets, see below:

**Works for:**

- L Preview
- 4.4

**Doesn't work for:**

- 2.3.3
- 4.1.2
- 4.3

This happens when using Android Studio 0.8.1, although I remember having the same problem on 0.6.1 also.

Comment: Any luck? Having the same issue.

Comment: Hell no. This is very annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on Android Studio 0.8.13 now, with the newly updated AVD Manager and it seems to be working perfectly. I was able to create a Nexus S with 2.3.3 APi 10. First time Host GPU was on and the screen was blank the whole time, even if the AVD started successfully. After turning Host GPU off, I got the screen working too.

Answer (score 30):

I was also facing the same issue. If you are using android studio, go to file->Invalidate caches/Restart, then click on "Invalidate and restart". It will work fine. :)