# What does the error mean in launching AVD

Tags: android, eclipse, mobile, error-handling, eclipse-plugin

[image][image]!When I tried to launch the AVD in eclipse, I've found the below error. I have installed everything as per manual but found error in loading AVD. The below image describes the error i have seen in launching AVD.Is the eclipse luna version is stable with android development.
[]This is a new error facing when i tried to start a AVD after restarting. [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpPGO.png)

Comment: Have you installed the Google API system image for API 21 ?

Comment: yes, @DavidJhons. I've installed all the listings in API21

Comment: try these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548666/error-avd-2-3-is-not-valid-unknown-target-android-10-in-home-user-android

Answer (score 0):

-Try **restarting** the ***eclipse*** and your ***system*** after installing all the softwares.

Comment: Hi, @Hardi Patel It worked after restarting and shows a new kind of error in it now.

Comment: Hello! thats nice that it worked! so now time to solve new erros! you can share that what kind of error were there.!

Comment: I've uploaded the new error in question itself, click on the 3rd image. You can see new error.